# EF Code-First Composite "Navigation" Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I've searched the already answered questions but found no answer to my problem. Shame on me.

I have this situation:

```
public class Content
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(36, ErrorMessage="Must have 36 characters")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Must have a unique GUID")]
    public string GUID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RegionalInfo> RegionalInfo { get; set; }
}

public class RegionalInfo
{
    [Key]
    public virtual Content Content { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage="ID must have 5 characters")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}", ErrorMessage = "ID must be in ISO 639 standard")] 
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

But I can't get this to work. EF says that "RegionalInfo has no Key defined".

To be short, I'm trying to make a composite key on this class "RegionalInfo" that includes The Content.GUID and the Region.ID.

For every single UNIQUE Content in the Contents table, many "Translations" will exist in the RegionalInfo table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make the assumption your using a DbContext. Under that assumption you should define your keys in the RegionalInfo class like so

```
public class RegionalInfo
{
    [Key]
    public String ContentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Content Content { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string RegionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

and in your context class you do the following:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Composite key definition
        modelBuilder.Entity<RegionalInfo>().HasKey(x => new { x.ContentId, x.RegionId });
        // And if I remember correctly this was required in order to do
        // var x = contentObject.RegionalInfo.Where(....) stuff
        modelBuilder.Entity<RegionalInfo>().HasRequired<Content>(x => x.Content).WithMany(x => x.RegionalInfo).HasForeignKey(x => x.ContentId);
    }
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Is this code on the context class necessary in order to the composite key to work? Will this avoid the unique check on a single column that integrates the composite key and check only both columns?

Comment: As for your first  question, I tried this myself yesterday: for the HasKey() it was necessary in my case. Without it I still got the "RegionalInfo has no Key defined" exception. The HasRequired() line I really am not sure about. I copied that from a similar situation I have as well (an Image entity, Gallery entity and ImageGallery entity where Gallery holds a collection of Images). As for your second question, in the RegionalInfo table a primary key will be generated consisting of both ContentId and RegionId, so that combo is unique, not a single column.